# Java EE Websocket programmatic Endpoint how to use Pathparams?

Tags: java, websocket, glassfish, endpoint

I'm fairly new to Java EE, so don't be to harsh with me, if what I'm asking doesn't make sense to you. I followed some tutorial for implementing the websocket api, essentially creating two classes. First a endpoint class looking like this:

```
public class ChatEndpoint extends Endpoint {
    private static final ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Session> peers = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(ChatEndpoint.class.getName());

    @Override
    public void onOpen(Session session, EndpointConfig endpointConfig) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, "New session opened");
        peers.add(session);

        session.addMessageHandler(new MessageHandler.Whole<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(String message) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, String.format("Received message: %s", message));
                try {
                    broadcastMessage(message, session);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.SEVERE, null, e);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason closeReason) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.INFO, String.format("Session closed with reason %s", closeReason.getReasonPhrase()));
    }

    public void broadcastMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException {
        for (Session peer : peers) {
            peer.getBasicRemote().sendText(message);
        }
    }
}
```

...and my config class:

```
public class ServerConfig implements ServerApplicationConfig {
    @Override
    public Set<ServerEndpointConfig> getEndpointConfigs(Set<Class<? extends Endpoint>> endpointClasses) {
        Set<ServerEndpointConfig> results = new HashSet<>();

        for (Class endpointClass : endpointClasses) {
            if (endpointClass.equals(ChatEndpoint.class)) {
                ServerEndpointConfig serverEndpointConfig = ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create(endpointClass, "/chat").build();
                results.add(serverEndpointConfig);
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getAnnotatedEndpointClasses(Set<Class<?>> endpointClasses) {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}
```

Now as you can see I've taken the programmatic and not the annotation way to do this. I know using the annotation way of deployment, I can specify path parameters, which I then receive in onMessage from my client. So how does this work with the a programmatic endpoint deployment?

Comment: `extends Endpoint`: what is the `Endpoint` class package? I can't really see which websocket implementation you are using. Which tutorial did you follow?

Comment: I'm using the Java EE websocket API. So it's from the package javax.websocket.Endpoint. I followed a tutorial from udemy.

Comment: Ok I'm an idiot, there is actually a method to retrieve the path params over the session object.

Answer (score 1):

old question, but just in case someone comes here looking:
the trick is to add pathParams to the path passed to `create(...)` the same way as in case of `@ServerEndpoint` annotation. So for example:
`ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create(endpointClass, "/chat/{room}")`
After that pathParams can be obtained in the endpoint using `Session.getPathParameters()`.